# Eclipse: Errors exist in active configuration of project "<project_name>"

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging

Project has been build successfully, but I got following error message while debugging in "Error in Workspace" pop-up window.

Error in Workspace:

```
Errors exist in active configuration of project "<project_name>". Proceed with launch?
```

I am using following version of Eclipse.

```
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Helios Service Release 2
```

I've imported this project as "C/C++ > Existing Code as Makefile Project".

Is anyone have any idea how to get rid of this error ?

Please let me know if I've missed something to mention here..

Comment: were you able to resolve this??

Answer (score 2):

I meet the problem too, and now it is fixed simply by **deleting the "Debug" or "Release" folder**.These two folders ware build after compiling,but they seem not to refesh automaticaly.So I delete them and compile again,and fixed.
My environment is :eclipse neno 4.6.0,JDK 1.8.0_92 64 bit,c++ prject.

Comment: So every time I try to launch the program I should delete the Debug folder?!

Comment: @BilalAhmed deleting it (or renaming it) once fixed it permanently for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the **Debug Folder** and run it. This might allow the program to execute.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same annoying problem, and I think I just found the solution:

- go to the Problems tab
- Right-click on Errors
- Delete the errors

I had cppcheck errors that prevented me from running my programs without this warning. Removing them solved the problem. And building again does not make the popup come back.